# SQL Server 2005: Creating an SP with a temp table returning null results

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I'm a little new to SQL server

I have created an SP that does the following

```
begin
    creates temp table
    inserts into temp table from another table with criteria
    right joins temp table to another table to return results
end
```

When I execute the SP the results of the temp table are all null. 
I originally had this as a batch sql separated with GO which worked fine.
When I wrapped it into an SP and removed the GO the temp table part of the join are all NULL

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean "the results of the temp table are all null".  The temporary table only exists within the scope of the stored procedure.

Comment: This would be a lot easier to answer with the actual SP code and some sample data - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please post the full sp so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Hi Guys I replaced the temp table with a table variable and it now works -